# nginx post information before proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, matomo

In Nginx am looking to post to a URL prior to calling proxy_pass, i.e.

```
location / {

    <! --- Post to a URL here -->

    proxy_set_header Correction "";
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_buffering        on;
    proxy_cache_background_update on;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 1440m;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;   
    proxy_cache $mydomian_proxy;        
    proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
    autoindex on;
    proxy_pass https://to  . com$request_uri;
  }
```

The URL post is to Matoomo tracking API e.g.

```
 https://matomo-server/matomo.php?_cvar={"1":["OS","iphone 5.0"],"2":["Matomo Mobile Version","1.6.2"],"3":["Locale","en::en"],"4":["Num Accounts","2"]}&action_name=View settings&url=http://mobileapp.matomo.org/window/settings &idsite=8876&rand=351459&h=18&m=13&s=3 &rec=1&apiv=1&cookie=1&urlref=https://iphone.mobileapp.piwik.org&_id=af344a398df83874 &_idvc=19&res=320×480&
```

I hope this may sense?

If you know how this can be achieve or a different approach to achieving this, it would be very helpful.

Thanks, Pete